# hhline fails to adhere to entries when using multirow statement

Tags: multirow, hhline, cellcolor

Here's the MWE (I'm using MikTeX 2.9 in combination with TeXworks):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\definecolor{tch}{gray}{0.4}
\definecolor{tc3}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{tc4}{gray}{0.80}

\newcommand{\hlc}[1]{\cellcolor{tc3}\centering{}#1}
\newcommand{\hld}[1]{\cellcolor{tc4}\centering{}#1}
\newcommand{\hldx}[1]{\cellcolor{tc4}#1}
\newcommand{\hc}{\cellcolor{tc3}\ }
\newcommand{\hd}{\cellcolor{tc4}\ }

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{%
>{\raggedright}p{7.5em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
>{\raggedright}p{7.5em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
>{\raggedright}p{7.5em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{11em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
}
\arrayrulecolor{white}\hline\rowcolor{tch}
   \color{white}{\bf Left preamp} & 
   \color{white}{\bf Right preamp} & 
   \color{white}{\bf Wiring} &
   \color{white}{\bf Description} \\
\hld{AUDIO-L\\(O)} &\hlc            &\hld{25\,cm (10\,in) shielded}&\hldx{Voice output x}\\
\hline
\hld{AGC-L\\(O)}   &\hlc            &\hld{15\,cm (6\,in)  shielded}&\hldx{Voice output y}\\
\hline
\hld{EXC-L\\(O)}   &\hld{abcd\\(I)} &\hld{20\,cm (8\,in)  shielded}&\hldx{Voice output z}\\
\hline
\hlc               &\hlc            &\hld{25\,cm (10\,in) shielded}&\hd\\
\hhline{=--~}
\hlc               &\hlc            &\hld{25\,cm (10\,in) shielded}&\multirow{-2}={\hldx{Excitation signals for both sides of the xyz}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

I wouldn't expect the double horizontal line to go beyond the first column. The use of `\hhline{=--~}` is just an example for better visualization. What I actually want to use is `\hline{---~}`. `\cline` doesn't work at all in this situation (no line shows up). **How do I make sure I don't get a line cut across my multirow cell?**

Unrelated to my main question, I don't know where the extra space above the text in the headers is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to make line through `multirow` cell invisible is to color it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, hmargin=2cm, vmargin=3cm}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\definecolor{tch}{gray}{0.4}
\definecolor{tc3}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{tc4}{gray}{0.80}

\newcommand{\hlc}[1]{\cellcolor{tc3}\centering{}#1}
\newcommand{\hld}[1]{\cellcolor{tc4}\centering{}#1}
\newcommand{\hldx}[1]{\cellcolor{tc4}#1}
\newcommand{\hc}{\cellcolor{tc3}\ }
\newcommand{\hd}{\cellcolor{tc4}\ }

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{%
>{\raggedright}p{7.5em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
>{\raggedright}p{7.5em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
>{\raggedright}p{7.5em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{11em}%
}
\arrayrulecolor{white}\hline\rowcolor{tch}
   \color{white}{\bf Left preamp} &
   \color{white}{\bf Right preamp} &
   \color{white}{\bf Wiring} &
   \color{white}{\bf Description} \\
\hld{AUDIO-L\\(O)} &\hlc            &\hld{25\,cm (10\,in) shielded}&\hldx{Voice output x}\\
\hline
\hld{AGC-L\\(O)}   &\hlc            &\hld{15\,cm (6\,in)  shielded}&\hldx{Voice output y}\\
\hline
\hld{EXC-L\\(O)}   &\hld{abcd\\(I)} &\hld{20\,cm (8\,in)  shielded}&\hldx{Voice output z}\\
\hline
\hlc               &\hlc            &\hld{25\,cm (10\,in) shielded}&\hd\\
\hhline{--->{\arrayrulecolor{tc4}}-}  % <---
\hlc               &\hlc            &\hld{25\,cm (10\,in) shielded} &\multirow{-2}={\hldx{Excitation signals for both sides of the xyz}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**

in case that you like to have thicker line between last two rows (as you show in image in question, than you should change used `\hhline{=--~}` with

```
\hhline{--->{\arrayrulecolor{tc4}\doublerulesepcolor{tc4}}=}  % <---
```

instead of `\hhline{--->{\arrayrulecolor{tc4}}-}  % <---` in mwe above. than you will obtain:

[image]

Comment: Oh, that works quite well indeed. Thanks for your help.One thing though, in case there are more `\hline` and `\hhline` to follow, the color needs to be set back. In my case: `\hhline{--->{\arrayrulecolor{tc4}}->{\arrayrulecolor{white}}}`

Comment: @Hansel, change color is for all line segments after change of color (until you change it again).  for details how to color `\hhline` see documentation of the package `colortbl`, page 6.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to draw a full `hhline`, with the last segment of the color of the background. I took the opportunity to simplify your code, with the `\columncolor` command. The unwanted vertical spacing in the first row is solved with the `\thead` command from `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\definecolor{tch}{gray}{0.4}
\definecolor{tc3}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{tc4}{gray}{0.80}

\newcommand{\hlc}[1]{\cellcolor{tc3}\centering{}#1}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\raggedright\normalsize\bfseries\color{white}}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{l}
\begin{tabular}{
*{3}{>{\columncolor{tc4}\centering}p{7.5em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}}%
>{\columncolor{tc4}\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{11em}!{\color{white}\vrule width 0.8pt}%
}
\arrayrulecolor{white}\hline\rowcolor{tch}
 \thead{Left preamp }&
   \thead{Right preamp} &
   \thead{Wiring} &
   \thead{Description} \\
 AUDIO-L\\(O) &\hlc & 25\,cm (10\,in) shielded & Voice output x \\
\hline
AGC-L\\(O) &\hlc & 15\,cm (6\,in) shielded & Voice output y \\
\hline
EXC-L\\(O) & abcd\\(I) & 20\,cm (8\,in) shielded & Voice output z \\
\hline
\hlc &\hlc & 25\,cm (10\,in) shielded & \\
\hhline{---|>{\arrayrulecolor{tc4}}->{\arrayrulecolor{white}}}
\hlc &\hlc & 25\,cm (10\,in) shielded & \multirow{-2}={Excitation signals for both sides of the xyz} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip with `makecell`. The problem though is that if the text is wider than the assigned field width, it doesn't do a linebreak.

Comment: Yes, but I think that for a column head, which is not ordinary text, it's better to choose the break point.

Answer (score 0):

For information, here is an easy way to create that tabular with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}
  [hvlines-except-borders,rules={color=white,width=1pt}]
  {ccm[l]{7.5em}p[l]{11em}}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor[gray]{0.4}{1}
  \cellcolor[gray]{0.85}{2-2,3-2,5-1,5-2,6-1,6-2}
  \rectanglecolor[gray]{0.80}{2-1}{4-1}
  \cellcolor[gray]{0.80}{4-2}
  \rectanglecolor[gray]{0.80}{2-3}{6-4}
\Body
\RowStyle[color=white]{\sffamily\bfseries}
  Left preamp & Right preamp & Wiring & Description \\
  \Block{}{AUDIO-L\\(O)} &                     & 25\,cm (10\,in) shielded & Voice output x \\
  \Block{}{AGC-L\\(O)}   &                     & 15\,cm (6\,in)  shielded & Voice output y \\
  \Block{}{EXC-L\\(O)}   & \Block{}{abcd\\(I)} & 20\,cm (8\,in)  shielded & Voice output z \\
                         &                     & 25\,cm (10\,in) shielded 
         & \Block{2-1}{Excitation signals for both sides of the xyz} \\
                         &                     & 25\,cm (10\,in) shielded \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]